# Using Ajax to get value of javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Long time stackoverflow user but first time poster! I recently made a very simple little browser based game, and when I say simple I cannot stress this enough.

Anyway, the entire game logic is in one little javascript file. In that file I have a variable called value, and it contains the players score.

The user at any given time during gameplay is allowed to click Submit, and this then uses a php script to access and write their username and hopefully soon their score to my database.

The problem I am having and I know quite a few people new to Ajax have had is, how do I send the value of the javascript variable value to my php page which handles sending the variables to my database?

I have read quite a bit on this and can't seem to get it working. So starting from scratch, assume I have a functioning javascript file with the value variable containing the score. How do I send the score to the php file using ajax? Where would I place the Ajax code?

Thank you stackoverflow! Also I already know that javascript resides on the client side and php runs on the server side, I just would like to know how to properly send the score to the php file, that is all! Thanks again stackoverflow!

EDIT: Because I seem to be getting down voted this is what I have but it does not work:

My Ajax:

```
function ajaxCall() {alert("To AJAX: the value is: " + value);

    $.ajax
    (   {
            type: "POST",
            url: "handler.php",
            data: {'value' : value}, 
            success: function(response)
            { alert("The value was passed!")}
        }
    );};
```

ajaxCall();

Part of handler.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['value']))

{
$value = $_POST['value']."";
var_dump($value);
}

var_dump($_POST['value']);
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work" in the code you have? Your Ajax call looks fine. Maybe there is a problem with your PHP script. Add an `error` handler or inspect the network tab of your browser's developer tools and see if the PHP throws any error. Since you seem to use jQuery, have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ as well.

Comment: @Felix, the dump only shows NULL. Would Firebug work for debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this,

your ajax.js should contain this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#submitscore").click(function(event){
     var user = $('#username').val();
     var value = document.getElementById('yourscore').innerHTML;
      $.post( 
         "submitscore.php",
         { username: user, score: value }
           );
  });
});
```

Your other file should have a button with the id "submitscore"

```
Hi, <input type="text" id="username" size="12"><br/>
Your Score is : <span id="yourscore">5000</span><br/>
<button id="submitscore">Submit Score</button>
```

And in that submit file, use this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['score'])||isset($_REQUEST['username']))
{
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$value = $_REQUEST['score'];
var_dump($value);
//Your Insertion/Updation Databse Script
}
```

Comment: So you are saying just have the second line you mentioned inside of the game.js?

Comment: I changed your button code to this:
<form method="post" action="handler.php"> <button id="submitscore">Submit Score</button></form>
But it is still saying NULL

Comment: You dont need to put it in a form. Just use button and be sure to include ajax.js and jquery.min.js in your HTML page.

Comment: Yes the head of the main html page is this:
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
 <script src="game.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

Comment: there is no attribute as `language=""` (as per w3Schools - google script attributes) in script tab, please remove it. Also which version of jQuery does jQuery.js has. I would advise you to use the original jQuery from jquery's site `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Okay I just made those changes. Now clicking Submit Score places a 5000 into the score sheet. How can I pass the users score instead of 5000?

Comment: Did a little more changes to HTML and ajax.js, Should Work :) (Edited above) Please post this as an answer if its working now)

Comment: I had it posting 5000 as the score with your older code, now it does not seem to want to post at all.

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your requirements. It should work fine. If you still have a problem running this code. Create another question. These comments are running way too long!!

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that sets a variable. Be sure to define the variable in advance, so that it can be accessed outside of the function

```
function ajaxCall() {
    alert("To AJAX: the value is: " + value);
    var response_value; // define here or you won't be able to access it outside of success: f()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handler.php",
        data: {'value' : value}, 
        success: function(response) {
            response_value = response;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Also please don't use a semicolon after `function() {}`. Sublime Text does that, still the syntax is incorrect.

Edit: I recommend you to change the PHP file to directly output a JSON file.
Things to consider when doing this:

- Set the content-type with `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`
- Generate a PHP array or a single variable (e.g. `$result_array`)
- Encode it to utf-8 JSON using PHP: `$json_string = json_encode($result_array); $json_string = utf8_encode($json_string);`
- Then simply `echo($json_string);`
- Tell jQuery that you are using JSON: Add `dataType: json` to your $.ajax() config

Comment: I will try all of these responses! And yes I did just switch to Sublime from Notepad ++ not sure how I feel about it.

Comment: If you are new to Sublime Text, check this out when you have a free hour [Tuts+: Perfect Workflow in Sublime Text 2](https://tutsplus.com/course/improve-workflow-in-sublime-text-2/)

Comment: I did it like you mentioned and I can still only get it to display NULL

Comment: JavaScript itself will not set a variable to `NULL`, it would set it to `undefined` instead. Please check that your PHP file doesn't answer with `null`

Comment: A nice answer Tobias! Although I recommended using utf8_encode on data before using json_encode. json_encode will only work with UTF8 strings and may return null if a non-utf8 character is found.